# SQL Server 2012 - Query columns based on condition

Tags: sql-server, database

I am trying to query for a table based on a condition. For example let's say I have table A with columns c1, c2, c3, c4, and c5.

Pseudo code:

```
If c5='Y'
Then
    select c1, c2 from A
else
    select c3, c4 from A
```

I am looking for something like the following:

```
case when c5='Y' then select c1, c2 from A
else select c3, c4 from A
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are you having a problem with specifically?

Comment: I only want to return specific columns based on a given condition

Comment: You should look at the CASE expression. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

Comment: I understand but what have you tried and what isn't working?  We expect a little bit of work to be shown instead of "Do this for me please and thank you".

Comment: So i have been trying variations of the case statement above. Is something like this possible?

Comment: You need to be aware that `CASE` is an **expression** - it can evaluate conditions and return a value. It is **not** a flow-control statement like it might be in other languages - it cannot be used to control the flow of your execution - it's just an expression

Comment: Right so just looking for some direction on how to proceed with returning specific columns based on some condition.

Comment: Did you even look at the link I provided? It shows you the exact syntax and usage of this.

Comment: @Sean Yeah i looked but case does not solve problem that i'm trying to solve. And i already am familiar with case which i have been trying for the last hour.

Comment: You say you are familiar with the case expression but the code you posted is not at all how it works. What you posted for code doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Sean I know it doesn't but i was trying to make case work because that was my first instinct. The solution below solved my problem. Thanks

Comment: What solution below? The only answer I see is the one I just now posted. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your case expression code doesn't make sense logically. You have to put the case expression on the row, not the table. Something like this.

```
select case when c5 = 'Y' then c1 else c3 end as MyFirstColumn
    , case when c5 = 'Y' then c2 else c4 end as MySecondColumn
from A
```

Comment: You say this works but the output is nothing like what you stated does work. I am glad you found a solution but I am not convinced you know which one is correct.

Comment: The output i am looking for is the values from columns based on a condition. The column name in the output doesn't matter so this solution works. The solution i posted below works as well.

Answer (score 0):

So the following solved the problem i was having:

```
if(exists(select top 1 1 from A where c5 = 'Y'))
begin
select c1, c2 from A
end
else
begin
select c3, c4 from A
end
```